# Java Thread Pool task execution queueing

Tags: java, multithreading

When using a java thread pool through the ThreadPoolExecutor, are all tasks queued before they are executed? Or are they queued only when there are no threads available (the number of running threads is equal or higher than the core pool size)?

Comment: Does the "**Core and maximum pool sizes**" section in [ThreadPoolExecutor](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) answer your question?

Answer (score 6):

**Task submitters** always send the tasks to the **queue** *(or try to)* , as there's no direct connection between them and the pooled threads ( *and for a good reason* ).

[image]

### ***Unbounded queues***

Regarding your question, even if a thread is avaliable, the task will first be inserted in the queue, and then pulled by the choosen free thread. If there are no avaliable threads, the submitters will still place the tasks into the queue.
In resume, the flow is always `Submitter -> Queue -> Thread`.

Unbounded queues often define a max size of INTEGER.MAX_VALUE, which is enough in 99% of the time for avoiding the submitter block.

### ***Size limited queues***

If there are no avaliable positions in the queue, the submitters could implement different mechanisms, for example:

- **Caller-Runs**: In which the submitter is the one who runs the task.
- **Blocking behaviour**: The submitter may try to insert the task the queue (forever or within a timeout, before discarding it).
- **Discard policy**: The queue could be configured to remove the oldest queued task if a new one tries to be inserted.

---

Regardless of the mechanism used, the flow of the task (if everything works properly) is:

**`Submitter -> Queue -> Thread`.**

In worse scenarios, this flow could be:

`Submitter --> Submitter` *(queue full and caller-runs)*

`Submitter --> Queue --> GarbageCollector`  *(queue full and discarded as it was the oldest task)*

`Submitter --> GarbageCollector` *(queue full and discarded after failed retries)*

---

In no case the flow would be

**`Submitter --> Thread`**

Avoiding a direct connection between submitters and the thread pool gives this system an asynchronous nature, in which the queue represents the "safety window".
This way:

- `Submitters` are not *ever* blocked (*using unbounded queues*).
- `Submitters` are only blocked if the queue is full and the mechanism implements the **Blocking behaviour** (*using bounded queues*).
- `Threads` don't have to cope with direct synchronous petitions from the Task Submitters.
- `Submitters` and `Threads` avoid complex synchronization mechanisms, as they don't have to negotiate directly.
- If the `Submitters` stop by some error or are deliverately stopped, `Threads` could still continue working by pulling the pending queued tasks.
- In the same way, if the `Threads` are stopped, `Submitters` could still be able to continue working, placing the tasks in the `queue` for future processing.  *(using unbounded queues).*

With this in mind, it's important to monitor the `queue`'s contents and its max size, is order to avoid `OOM` exceptions. This could happen if submitters send too many tasks and/or too fast, while the threads aren't able to follow their rythm. This would involve an ascending lag inside the queue, hence a possible `Out of Memory` error.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Another question, if all tasks go to the queue, then does it makes sense to have a queue size smaller than the core pool size?

Let's imagine that I have a queue of 5 and a core pool size of 10, if I push 10 tasks to the thread pool at the same time, wouldn't the other 5 be rejected?

Comment: By default, yes, it will reject them and throw a RejectedTaskExecution. It gives back the Submitter the responsability of that task. There are different options. Caller-Runs is one of them: if a task can't be queued, the submitter thread will run the task. Other option is to force the submitter to wait, by constantly trying to queue a rejected task inside a loop clause. This lead to blocking the submitter until it is able to insert the task into the queue. In resume, you could implement any solution that fits your needs.

Comment: This links gives excellent info: https://10kloc.wordpress.com/2012/11/04/custom-threadpoolexecutor-for-handling-rejected-tasks/

Comment: Regarding your other question, it may make sense in the following scenario: imagine that you must discard old tasks (because , f.e, they are invalid after certain timeout) If the queue is defined to discard the oldest entry if a new task is received while the queue is full, this will effectively avoid processing those messages. It could also make sense if the resources are low and you don't mind/can afford a lower process rate, in return of a low but consistent performance that doesn't crash.

Comment: Edited the answer as I noticed I assumed only unboundedqueues were to be used.

Comment: Wow! Brilliant description!